# jinja2: print red text if variable evaluates to None

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have several variables that are fetched from a database and passed to a jinja2 template via flask. Sometimes the values exist, sometimes they do not. I want to print out a RED default message if the data doesn't exist, such as "Data unavailable". This is what I have so far but I can't find a way to turn it red.

```
{{ variable | default('Data unavailable') }}
```

Comment: How do you normally turn text red?  Is this an html template?  Do you have css classes for turning things red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a conditional style around your variable placeholder.

```
<span{% if (!variable) %} style="color: red"{% endif %}>
   {{ variable | default('Data unavailable') }}
</span>
```